# Use old and new value on Javascript after onChange of Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to pass on a function the old and the new value of a select element with the following way:

```
<select class="browser-default" id="countries" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="getCurrency(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
   <option value="1">....</option>
   <option value="2">....</option>
</select>

var getCurrency = function(country) {
   currency_value = country.value;
   country_name = country.options[country.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
   old_value = country.oldvalue;
   if ( oldvalue === "") {
    oldvalue = 10;
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. It doesn't pass the old value to the function. I saw something similar to another question in Stackoverflow and try to reproduce it.

Comment: There is no option like old value for select element. You can use a global variable to capture the last value selected in the dropdown.

Comment: This is what the code should do on the "onchange" place. Setting the current value to a variable `oldvalue` before passing it to the function.

Comment: It seems to work. What you want to achieve? Keep in mind that the first time the value is the disabled one. Here is and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v64bjkww/)

Comment: I edited the question with the extra part where I check if the oldvalue is empty. I try to create a function which will change a number for one currency to another. It's not money currency but a custom one. That's why I don't use a ready function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="countries" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="getCurrency(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
   <option value="1">India</option>
   <option value="2">Australia</option>
  <option value="3">USA</option>
</select>

<script>
  var oldValue = $("#countries").val();
  var newValue;
  $("#countries").change(function(){
    newValue=$(this).val();
    alert(oldValue + " : " + newValue);
    oldValue=newValue;
  });
 
  </script>
```